OKTA sso for Salesforce CanvasApp ServiceNow
We are adding ServiceNow as a canvas app to Salesforce  and we have Servicenow and Salesforce both integrated with okta for SSO.
When we click on ServiceNow canvas app, it gets redirected to Okta for authentication, want to know if there is way to login automatically and not prompt for username and password?
Single Sign On to ServiceNow canvas application

This doesn't sound like a programming question? If it is, can you [edit] it and add your code as a [mcve]? If not, it's probably off-topic here (check the [help/on-topic]), but it may fit on [salesforce.se]. Check their help pages to see what level of detail questions require there.
